# Incorrect Comparison in Sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, comparison

> **Despite its** name, the guinea pig is not **a member** of the pig family **but a** rodent **from the Andes** in South America.

Apparently in this sentence none of the bolded parts are incorrect. I can't understand why not, isn't this sentence comparing 'a member' to 'rodent'.

Shouldn't it be something like this

> **Despite its** name, the guinea pig is not **a member** of the pig family **but belongs to a rodent family from the Andes** in South America.

How is the first sentence grammatically correct and what meaning does it convey.

Comment: Assuming that it's correct scientifically, the likely intended meaning is: "Despite its name, the guinea pig is not a member of the pig family but [the guinea pig is] a rodent from the Andes in South America."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **not / but** pair indicates the semantic structure - these two parts are on the same level.

This means, the sentence structure is like this:

```
Despite its name,  
        the guinea pig is  
                   **not** a member 
                             of the pig family
                   **but** a rodent
                             from the Andes in South America.
```

Comment: I can't understand though since "the guinea pig" is referred to as a member in the first part then shouldn't we write "........ but is a member of the rodent family from the Andes.."

Comment: There is *no need* to do so. Its simply **not** (a) **but** (b), with (a) and (b) phrased independently. Let me give you a random example: "A quince is **not** (a dance), **but** (one of my grandmother's favourite fruits)." The parts *after* the not/but are semantically linked but not necessarily follow the same pattern. And there is no *rodent family* from the Andes, but guinea pigs simply are rodents, according to your text. In your example, no elipsis (a "leaving out" of equal parts) of "member" or "family" is involved.